# Summations with power of DiscreteDelta

Tags: discontinuity

Expression

> Sum[DiscreteDelta[a - 1]^2, {a, -∞, ∞}]

evaluates to 1, as expected, but

> Sum[DiscreteDelta[a - b]^2, {a, -∞, ∞}]

does not converge, according to `Mathematica`. Is there a way to cleanly circumvent this?

Comment: `DiscreteDelta[]` evaluates to `1` only if the argument is zero. MMA cannot decide, wether `a-b` equals zero, because properties of  b aren't known!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann However, `Sum[DiscreteDelta[a - b], {a, -[Infinity], [Infinity]}]` does give zero. I think this specifically a problem with power.

Comment: I believe the result  `Sum[DiscreteDelta[a - b], {a, -[Infinity], [Infinity]}]==1` cannot  be true for arbitrary b (If I understand the definition `DiscreteDelta` right)

Comment: OK, I see. Carl Woil also suggested that this is a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Assuming:

```
Assuming[
    b ∈ Integers,
    Sum[DiscreteDelta[a-b]^2,{a,-∞,∞}]
]
```

> 1

Comment: Any ideas why I don't need this when the `DiscreteDelta` is not squared?

Comment: @WeatherReport My guess is that the unsquared version is a bug. For instance, if b=.5 the answer is incorrect.

Comment: Hmm. I was really looking for an abstract notion of delta-symbol. which would evaluate `Sum[AbstractDelta[a-b]f[a],{a,allvalues}]` to `f[b]`. Like a `DiracDelta` but which should not diverge when squared. I thought that `DiscreteDelta` serves that purpose. But you are saying its probably a bug:) Is there an abstract notion that I'm looking for?